# Не могу удалить каталог

Tags: linux, администрирование

Кто-то может это объяснить

```
$ pwd
/mnt/nas4free/lary/Beckup/opt/GNAT/2019/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1

$ ls -l
итого 0
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root users 0 сен 16 17:07 plugin

$ rmdir plugin/
rmdir: не удалось удалить 'plugin/': Каталог не пуст

$ ls -al plugin/
итого 0
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root users 0 сен 16 17:07 .
drwxrwxr-x. 2 root users 0 сен 16 17:07 ..
```

Как такое может быть ?! Каталог пуст, но *rmdir* удалитить его не может, так как он **не** пуст.

Единственная зацепка - каталог расположен на nsa4free сервере и смонтирован как типа *cifs*. Но какие тут проблемы могут быть - не понимаю.

Если попытаться посмотреть содержимое этого каталога пряма на сервере, зайдя по SSH, то тоже ничего нет:

```
nas4free: Beckup# cd opt/GNAT/2019/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.3.1
nas4free: 8.3.1# ls -al
total 3
drwxr-xr-x  3 lary  admin   5 Sep 16 17:07 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 lary  admin   3 Jun  8  2019 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 lary  admin  21 Dec  6  2020 adainclude -> rts-native/adainclude
lrwxrwxrwx  1 lary  admin  17 Dec  6  2020 adalib -> rts-native/adalib
drwxr-xr-x  2 lary  admin   5 Sep 16 17:07 plugin
nas4free: 8.3.1#
nas4free: 8.3.1# ls -al plugin/
nas4free: 8.3.1#
```

Но при попытке удаления этой директории возниакет та же самая ошибка:

```
nas4free: 8.3.1# rmdir plugin/
rmdir: plugin/: Directory not empty
```

Мистика... :-(

Comment: `rm -r` тоже не работает? может там какой-то скрытый файл, который самба-сервер не экспортирует?

Comment: @Fat-Zer - "rm -r тоже не работает? " - Да, не работает!  - "скрытый файл"  - так я же давал команду  *ls -al* - должна всё показать!

Comment: я имею в виду, что samba-сервер (в зависимости от своих настроек) может не отображать некоторые реально существующие файлы клиентам... собственно для проверки предлагаю, по возможности, подключиться к этому серверу по ssh и проверить, действительно ли этот каталог пуст...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Дописал в вопрос.

Comment: гм... значит проблема на стороне сервера... если верить гуглу, то в nas4free под капотом BSD'я... [вот здесь](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/unable-to-delete-empty-folder.28025/) подобное вызывалось ошибкам в ФС... можно попробовать отмонтировать и прогнать `fsck`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Почитал...  Перегрузил сервер. С локального хоста удалось удалить 3/4 "застрявших" файлов. Но несколько не получалось. Зашёл на сервер по SSH и удалось вычистить всё! Напишите в ответ - я плюс поставлю!

Comment: скорей всего, у меня так и не дойдут руки написать ответ... так что лучше напиши сам...